# Unable to get values in JSP in Struts2 Liferay6.2 Portlet

Tags: struts2, liferay-6, portlet

Brief Overview: I am trying to port a webapp based on Struts2 ,into a Struts2 Liferay portlet.

Problem definition: The values are fetched as NULL/Blank even if if the action Class method is setting the values properly in my variables.
I have tried printing out the values when my method is returned in Action Class and also in my jsp. The values are getting properly set as I can see it from the loggers put in place just before returning SUCCESS, but in the jsp I can see all the required set variables are blank!!

Code snippet:

In jsp the code is fetching the values as below:
For instance

```
<br>
<s:if test="%{xyz!= null}">
 <br />
  <div style="margin-left:9em;">
   <s:property value="xyz" escapeHtml="false"/> //never displayed as xyz is NULL 
  </div>
 <br /><br />
</s:if>
<br>
```

on printing out xyz: `<s:text name="%{xyz}"/>` , I get blank values , this happens for all the required values in the jsp.

The options I have tried out:

I have tried using : `%{#xyz}`, `%{xyz}`, but didn't helped.

struts.xml

```
<action name="selectSite" class="com.abc.xyz.LandingPageAction"
                     method="selectSite">
            <interceptor-ref name="abAjaxCallInterceptorStack" />
            <result name="success" >/WEB-INF/jsp/portal/LandingContent.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>xyz-portlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>       
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>  
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource> 
    </portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<br>
<s:if test="%{xyz!= null}">
 <br />
  <div style="margin-left:9em;">
   <s:property value="xyz" escapeHtml="false"/>
  </div>
 <br /><br />
</s:if>
<br>

<br />

<sj:tabbedpanel id="billTab" >
    <sj:tab id="overview" href="%{overviewURL}" label="Overview"
            target="overviewDiv" indicator="loadingInd" />
    <sj:tab id="invoices" href="%{invoiceURL}" label="Invoices" 
            target="invoicesDiv" indicator="loadingInd" />
    <div id="overviewDiv" ></div>
    <div id="invoicesDiv" ></div>

</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Comment: Why this code isn't working? The code that is not working not available.

Comment: The values are not fetched , however the required variables are being set in my ActionClass method , which returns SUCCESS. All the places where the it is expecting a value from the variables like %{abc}, is coming as blank.

Comment: modified the original post, if it helps.%{overviewURL}, %{invoiceURL} is fetched as blank

Comment: just wanted to add there is also a default interceptor which is executed on every request.

Comment: And you are saying that this was working in a regular web app and NOT working in the portlet?

Comment: yes ! correct..not working in a portlet environment !

Comment: You need to use `portletDefaultStack` instead of `defaultStack` in portlet environment.

Comment: Thx Aleksandr for reply, what all changes I will need to do? Do I need to include any specific jar ?Also, please bear with me, I am new to Struts2/Liferay altogether..:)

Comment: See the docs: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/portlet-plugin.html.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<s:if test="xyz!= null">
```

if xyz is on the valuestack then you don't need to use %

You can also use Set tag to expose these values such as

`<s:set var="varName" value="xyz"/>`then just refer to it as varName instead of #varName

If you are accessing vars in a different portlet you will have set the value for the variable as at least request scope like this

```
<s:set var="varName" value="xyz" scope="request"/>
```

Then you can access them like this from another portlet in the same page

```
<s:if test="#request.xyz != null">
```

Comment: The `<s:set>` `name` attribute is deprecated, and it is better to use `#varName`.

Comment: Yes, var instead of name

Comment: thanks for the replies !! I will just try it out and come back with queries :)

Comment: using xyz directly instead, didn't helped :(

Comment: you might want to try using

`#attr.xyz`

what this does is it checks page, request, session and application scopes in that order. if it still doesn't return anything then the problem is elsewhere. check if xyz is actually added as a parameter. I can see that you are simply forwarding to a jsp in your action in struts.xml. You could try a redirectAction and add the parameter as a param tag

Comment: @rpogonyi: An `redirectAction`? And redirect to what? Don't mislead the OP.

Comment: After using portletDefaultStack instead of defaultStack, I am getting the value of xyz in the jsp above : <s:property value="xyz"/>, however %{overviewURL}, %{invoiceURL} are still coming as blank, I will figure it out if I am missing something. Again, thanks a ton Aleks for your help !!

Comment: @AleksandrM : Need your help again! in the original post jsp page :  <sj:tabbedpanel id="billTab" > , href="%{overviewURL}" is a URL which forms a normal GET request like : http://localhost:8080/web/billOverviewAjax?billingAccountId=37527220&billTo=O&refId=96177&orgAccountId=gGrsoTqScml71z....in this case my action is not called which is "billOverviewAjax" defined in struts.xml file, how can I make it a portlet request? should I be using portlet:actionURL somehow?